# DynamoDB performance/cost difference between map or separate attributes

Tags: database-design, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

Since DynamoDB now supports JSON documents (the map type) and projections into documents, is there a **performance or cost difference** between storing a map as one attribute vs storing the fields as separate attributes?

For example, I have a table for API access to different sites. Most use a `client_id` and `client_secret`, some have an additional field like a `server_token`, and a few use something else. Is there a difference between storing items with a single map attribute or with multiple attributes?

```
id | name   | data
———————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
1  | Google | {client_id: XXX, client_secret: XXX}
2  | Uber   | {client_id: XXX, client_secret: XXX, server_token: XXX}
```

versus

```
id | name   | client_id | client_secret
————————————————————————————————————————
1  | Google | XXX       | XXX
========================================
id | name | client_id | client_secret | server_token
—————————————————————————————————————————————————————
2  | Uber | XXX       | XXX           | XXX
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In terms of performance or cost there shouldn't be any difference between using top level attributes vs nesting them under a `data` attribute.

However, as of today DyanmoDB does not support creating secondary indexes on nested attributes. Say in the future you needed to query this table by `client_id`, if you nested that attribute then you wouldn't be able to add a global secondary index on that attribute.

Comment: In theory, this looks right but any documentation from AWS or any benchmark tests done ?

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about the extensibility of your model: storing the data as multiple attributes allows you to update them atomically with no hassle, even in a distributed clients scenario.

If you store the data as a map, each time you want to update any value inside that map you have to re-write the entire map. That could be a lock nightmare in case there are many distributed clients attempting to modify different keys the same map at the same time.

Comment: Update expressions allow you to add/remove/update individual map values: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET.AddingNestedMapAttributes