# DynamoDB Map vs String Set data type. Which one quickly check the value exists?

Tags: database-design, amazon-dynamodb, nosql, dynamodb-queries

In my comment table, I want to store the list of users who have read the comment. I am considering using a String Set or a Map for the reader's column. Which data type would be better for quickly checking if a value exists?

The comment table structure is as follows:

```
comment_id = xxx-xxx-123
message = Sample Message
created = timestamp
readers = ??
```

If I use a String Set, I would store the data as `readers = ["userid1", "userid2"]`. If I use a Map, I would store the data as `readers = {"userid1": "timestamp", "userid2": "timestamp"}`.

I will be updating each item when users read the comment. For updating the record, which data type is better: String Set or Map?

According to this [Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64790345/3924535), Maps can lock in case there are many distributed clients attempting to modify different keys on the same map at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is pretty simple: If you don't need these "timestamps" as map values, then use a string set - it will be smaller and therefore cheaper to read and write. If you do need those timestamps, then obviously use a map - because a string set doesn't have this feature.

You should be aware the downsides like the ones you mentioned and additional ones which you didn't, are actually shared by *both* maps and sets:

1. When you use an item (read or write it), you pay by the length of the *entire* item. It doesn't help that you "just" want to check if a certain key exists in a set or a map - you still pay for reading the entire set or map. Same when "just" adding one more key to a set or map - you pay for writing again the entire item.
2. Point 1 means it is very expensive to have long sets/maps. But in addition to that, because the item size is limited to 400 KB ([see here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ServiceQuotas.html#limits-items)), the set/map can't grow huge even if you didn't mind the price. If you have lists that *can* grow very long, you should probably make them into independent items (i.e. items that have different sort key with the same partition key), not a map or a set.
3. Concurrent modifications to the same **item** (the entire thing holding the map or set) are serialized by DynamoDB, i.e., use "locking". There's no difference between two modifications to the same set or to the same map in that regard. That being said, you shouldn't be particularly concerned about this locking because it won't "cost" you anything - not in price (as mentioned above, the price of the write depends just on the length of the entire item being modified, not on any particular implementation details like locking) and not in performance (in DynamoDB, writes happen on a single "leader" node so locking on it is easy and efficient, and anyway happens on all write requests and not only during contention).

Answer (score 0):

String set is best, as it contains only unique items. And you can easily understand if an set `contains` an attribute.

Maps become cumbersome when they are deeply nested, so I would suggest keeping it simple, unless it's essential you store timestamp also.